# How to Replicate a Color in Final Cut Pro X

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, color-grading

I am editing video in Final Cut Pro X.  Within a video, I would like to create a title that uses a font color that matches a color within the video itself.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The key thing to realize is that double-clicking the text color within the Inspector brings up a separate color wheel window which contains an eyedropper.  Dragging the eyedropper to the color of interest within the video is how the color gets chosen for the title.

Here's a video on how to [replicate a color](https://youtu.be/-eNxhLsOZUY) within Final Cut Pro X.